# Live Agent addCustomDetail

Tags: visualforce, liveagent, customization

I have created a start page with chat button and deployment code and I want to get some custom value from start page to my preChatPage.  addCustomDetail(String label, String value, (optional) Boolean displayToAgent) is used to add custom values, I am not able to understand that how to retrive the the same value at preChatPage.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    liveagent.addCustomDetail('domain', 'c.cs14.visual.force.com');
    liveagent.init('https://d.la1-c2cs-iad.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '5726A0000001EJt', '00Dc0000003kA0U');
</script>
```

How to get the "domain" value in preChatPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `preChatInit` method to access the deployment information that has been passed into the chat through the addCustomDetail Deployment API method.

Please follow this Salesforce knowledge Article [How to pass values from Start Chat button to Pre-Chat Form](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206551&type=1)

**How to pass values from Start Chat button to Pre-Chat Form**

1. This code will be added to the page where you are adding chat button and deployment code

```javascript
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var test = liveagent.addCustomDetail('test','Test Value');
</script>
```

2. Add following code on the pre chat form page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var detailCallback = function (details){
    for(var i = 0; i < details.customDetails.length; i++) {
       if(details.customDetails[i].label == 'test'){
          console.log(details.customDetails[i].value);
        }
     }
 };
```

//First parameter is Chat URL. This is same as generated in Live Chat deployment code and can be used here
//This might be different for different users
//For example, in my Live chat deployment, the chat URL was 'https://d.la1c1.salesforceliveagent.com/chat' as defined in

```
liveagent.init('https://d.la1c1.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '5724000000000XX', '00De000000XXXXX');
liveagent.details.preChatInit('https://d.la1c1.salesforceliveagent.com/chat','detailCallback');
```